# Как изменить цвет текста в html?

Tags: html

Есть строка:

```html
<span class="cafe-site">Сайт:www.com.ua</span>
```

Нужно чтобы "сайт:" был обычным черным цветом, без изменений, а текст "www.com.ua" - красным

Помогите)

Comment: Обернуть их в разные теги

Comment: Можно например сделать так без использования дополнительного файла CSS:

<span class="cafe-site"><span style=“color: black”>Сайт:</span><span style=“color: red”>www.com.ua</span></span>

Или же используя дополнительный файл с css:

<span class="cafe-site"><span class=“class_black”>Сайт:</span><span class=“color_red”>www.com.ua</span></span>

А в файле css пишешь так 
.class_red{
      color: red;
}
.class_black{
      color: black;
}

Если текст у тебя на сайте весь чёрный, то можешь просто обернуть то что идёт после «Сайт:» и сделать так как показано в любом из 2 примеров.

Answer (score 1):

В идеале обернуть нужное в отдельный тег и его уже редактировать.

Если вариант [обратиться к данному тегу](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/child) через CSS:

```css
.cafe-site > span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="cafe-site">Сайт:<span>www.com.ua</span></span>
```

Или же использовать [инлайновые стили](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/style):

```html
<span class="cafe-site">Сайт:<span style="color:red">www.com.ua</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вероятно, это не из лучших решений, но**

Оберните слово "Сайт" в тег `<em>`:

```
<span class="cafe-site"><em class="site">Сайт:</em>www.com.ua</span>
```

И обратитесь к нему через css